# How to import java libraries in jsp code?

Tags: java, jsp, import

I have the following jsp code. I want to add libraries such as java.io.

How can I do this?

```
<% @page import=java.io.BufferedReader;
@page import=java.io.IOException;
@page import=java.io.InputStreamReader;
String IP=request.getParameter("IP");

String res="";

        Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process pr = run.exec("snmpget -v 2c -c public "+IP+" SNMPv2-MIB::sysUpTime.0");
        pr.waitFor();
        BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
        String line = "";
        //String res="";
            while ((line = buf.readLine()) != null)
            {
                res+=line+"\n";
            }
        int i=res.indexOf(")");
      //  System.out.println(i);

        res=res.substring(i+1).trim();

        //System.out.print(res);

    } catch (InterruptedException ex)
    {
        Logger.getLogger(myMain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(myMain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

%>
```

Comment: avoid that. java code should be in servlets, not JSPs

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are almost right, but you need to close the import tag, like this:

```
<%@ page import="java.io.BufferedReader" %>
```

To declare multiple imports you can either duplicate that entire tag, like so:

```
<%@ page import="java.io.BufferedReader" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.InputStreamReader" %>
```

or use a comma-separated list:

```
<%@ page import="java.io.BufferedReader,java.io.InputStreamReader" %>
```

For a multitude of reasons, though, I would not recommend mixing java code into your JSPs.

Comment: Or just `<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>`.