# How to call 'so file' function in jar library

Tags: java, linux, jsp, shared-libraries

I have a jar library that calls some functions in so file.

And I want to use the jar library in JSP project.

Importing jar library in JSP project was succeed.

But when I try to call jar library's function that uses so file's function, It gets link error.

- java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: [so library's function name that jar library calls]

How can I import the so library to call some functions from it?
(The caller should be Jar library)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import java libraries in jsp code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159276/how-to-import-java-libraries-in-jsp-code)

Comment: @mohammedkhan No, I succeed calling jar library. What I need is 'How should i 
 import so file to call from jar library'

Comment: if you can provide the code you're using then perhaps it would be easier to see what's going wrong.